# Why do I get a segmentation fault when getting file name using user input?

Tags: c, input, user-input

I will strip the code down to only the parts I am having trouble with.

When I do the following, the code works

```
int main() {        
    FILE * fptr1 = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    fread(data, sizeof(char), size, fptr1);
    .
    .
    .
    FILE * fptr2 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    fwrite(data, sizeof(char), size, fptr2);
    fclose(fptr2);
}
```

But when I use fgets to get the input and output file name using fgets or scanf, I get a segmentation fault.

```
int main() {

    char inputfile[100];
    char outputfile[100];
    printf("name of input file: \n");
    fgets(inputfile, 100, stdin);
    printf("name of output file: \n");
    fgets(outputfile, 100, stdin);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have been playing around with this for a while. I tried using scanf and tried changing the allocated sizes for inputfile and outputfile but I keep getting:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Check `inputfile` and `outputfile`. Do they contain the terminating `'\n'`?

Comment: Ok, but will the `\n` cause a segmentation fault? As far as I know, segmentation fault is caused by accessing memory outside of the allocated memory. Shouldn't the `\n ` simply cause the program not to be able to find the file because the name is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `fgets()`, the resulting filenames `inputfile` and `outputfile` contain the terminating newline characters. It causes the following `fopen()` failed and returned `NULL`.

However, you didn't check for nullity of `FILE*`'s before calling `fread()` or `fwrite()`, and this led to segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

A string inputted using `fgets()` contains a terminating '\n', which is usually unexpected. Although this won't cause a segfault directly, it may cause `fopen()` to return `NULL`, since it cannot find that file. Trying reading data from a null file pointer will cause a segfault.

Add

```
if(fptr1 == 0)
{
    perror("fopen()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

after your `fopen()` statements.